# ion-view cache & states with URL Parameters

Tags: ionic-framework

The cache mechanism of the ion-views seems broken when using URL Parameters in the view.

```
$stateProvider.
.state('a', {
  url: '/a',
  templateUrl: 'templates/a.html',
  controller: 'ACtrl'
})
.state('b', {
  url: '/b/:id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/b.html',
  controller: 'BCtrl'
})
```

In this example the state 'a' is cached and works as expected. But the state 'b' is just cached if the same id appears twice. So /b/1 and /b/2 results in different ion-view dom elements.
I would expect that the same ion-view dom element is used for all calls to /b/:id.

Is this a bug or works as expected? In my situation I want the "other" behaviour, any idea how to archive this?

Comment: It works that way, what you want is hardly be done by the 'ui-router'. But you can do it by another way that define all the 'id' in the '$scope',  and change 'id' in the controller instead of changing the 'state'.

Comment: Hm sad to hear that, so i have to do this by myself and save the id in a service or somewhere else :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to delete the ui-routing cache.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
    });
})
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Tried it, but the $viewContentLoaded is never executed in my case. Not sure why. But anyhow, i don't want to remove all views. I want to cache them but just one per state.